# How to get sections of SSRS report data on separate lines in the output file

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssms, ssrs-2012, rdl

I have a stored procedure in SSMS that looks something like this:

```
SELECT
    1 AS [Transaction Type 1]
    ,SOMEFIELD AS [Some Field]
    ,ANOTHERFIELD AS [Another Field]
    ,...

    ,2 AS [Transaction Type 2]
    ,SOMEOTHERFIELD AS [Some Other Field]
    ,YETANOTHERFIELD AS [Yet Another Field]
    ,...

    ,4 AS [Transaction Type 4]
    ,MOREFIELDS AS [More FieldS]
    ,EVENMOREFIELDS AS [Even More Fields]
FROM SomeTable
JOINS
WHERE
ORDER BY
```

The customer is requiring that, for each record in the output, each Transaction Type section (1,2,4) is on its own line in the file that SSRS generates when the report is run. They're processing the data from the output file that SSRS generates, so they're not concerned with how the report looks in the browser when the report is run, but the file should look something like this:

```
1|10354|99999-9999|O|SOMENAME|11161947|M|999-99-9999|SOMEADDRESS|SOMEADDRESS|SOMECITY|ST|99999|999-999-9999|CLI|99999999|99999999|O|S|
2|10354|99999-9999|O||||||||MSOMENAME|U61434|1790702207|465|||PODSTTRY|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
4|117245592|SOMECOMPANY|STDSNP|117245592|1|Self
1|10723|99999-9999|O|SOMENAME|08081934|M|999-99-9999|SOMEADDRESS||SOMECITY|ST|99999|999-999-9999|ER |99999999|99999999|O|M|
2|10723|99999-9999|O||||||||SOMENAME||1356982441|3119||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
4|4VH2R42VX92|SOMECOMPANY||4VH2R42VX92|1|Self
1|12318|99999-9999||SOMENAME|07201973|F|999-99-9999|SOMEADDRESS||SOMECITY|ST|99999|999-999-9999|CLI|99999999|99999999|O|M|
2|12318|99999-9999|||||||||SOMENAME||1194703439|1639||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
4|STLW01260703|SOMECOMPANY|36650|STLW01260703|1|Self
```

As I said above, in the file output each 1, 2, & 4 Type section is on its own line. However, I had to manually do the above file output sample for the purposes of this question, because the actual file output looks like this:

```
1|12318|99999-9999||SOMENAME|99999999|F|999-99-9999|SOMEADDRESS||SOMECITY|ST|99999|999-999-9999|CLI|99999999|99999999|O|M|2|12318|99999-9999|||||||||SOMENAME||99999999|1639||G68462||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||4|STLW01260703|SOMECOMPANY|36650|STLW01260703|1|Self
1|12328|99999-9999|O|SOMENAME|99999999|M|999-99-9999|SOMEADDRESS||SOMECITY|ST|99999|999-999-9999|CLI|99999999|99999999|O|S|2|12328|99999-9999|O||||||||SOMENAME||99999999|2447||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||4|CPWW01093606|SOMECOMPANY|20041|CPWW01093606|1|Self
1|12508|99999-9999|O|SOMENAME|99999999|F|999-99-9999|SOMEADDRESS||SOMECITY|ST|99999|999-999-99991|CLI|99999999|99999999|O|W|2|12508|99999-9999|O||||||||SOMENAME||99999999|2707||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||4|1XM0TM6DT02|SOMECOMPANY||1XM0TM6DT02|1|Self
1|13167|99999-9999||SOMENAME|99999999|F|999-99-9999|SOMEADDRESS||SOMECITY|ST|99999|999-999-9999|CLI|99999999|99999999|O|M|2|13167|99999-9999|||||||||SOMENAMEA||99999999|2159||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||4|9TP1NQ5MR03|SOMECOMPANY||9TP1NQ5MR03|1|Self
1|13673|99999-9999|O|SOMENAME|99999999|F|999-99-9999|SOMEADDRESS||SOMECITY|ST|99999|999-999-9999|CLI|99999999|99999999|O|M|2|13673|99999-9999|O||||||||SOMENAME||99999999|2707||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||4|DSTW00629242|SOMECOMPANY|XA061|DSTW00629242|1|Spouse
```

Each record generated by the stored procedure is on its own line. Sections 2 & 4 are on the same line as its correcsponding section 1 for each respective record.

The confusing part is, in VS for Business, where I'm working on the RDL, the layout looks like this:

[image: RDL layout in VS for Business]

And when the report is run in SSRS, the output looks like this:

[image: SSRS report output sample]

You'll notice that each Type section 1, 2, & 4 are on its own line for a given record, as intended.

I just can't figure out how to get it to save like that in the pipe-delimited text file. Frankly, we're stumped and are wondering if this is even possible in an SSRS RDL, save for creating a batch file after the file is generated that would put each section on its own line.

Comment: Don't use SSRS to create a pipe delimited file. Use an ETL process such as SSIS or `bcp`.

Comment: @marky This [link](https://youtu.be/htVyjI1P04o) might help you.

Comment: Just a comment on the link @scase posted. This will work fine if you are running SSRS on your local machine but you will obviously need to repeat the process of editing the config file on your production SSRS server to.

Comment: @sacse - Thanks, but the question isn't how to save the report data as a pipe-delimited file. As you can see in the two file examples above, we're already saving the report as a pipe-delimited file. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear on that. I'm trying to figure out how to save the file with the records split out, with each Type (1,2,4) on its own line. The first file output example, below the first screenshot shows what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @marky so, are you saying that you want to bypass the SSRS thing and generate the desired output (currently being delivered through SSRS reports) by running the procedure (in some fashion) only?

Comment: @sacse - Well, if that's what we'd need to do to get the needed file data output, then yes - whether through SSRS or run the Sproc and output the file directly (or however). The ultimate goal here is to get the data in the format as shown in the example from data generated by a stored procedure.

Comment: You would need to do it through the SP to get your results in separate lines probably by using union. Is there a way to determine when a transaction is type 1, 2 or 4 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, a Union won't work in this case, as each of the three type sections has a different number of fields. As in the code example at the top of my question, the Transaction Type 1//2/4 are hard-coded, this indicates when the respective section of data begins in the output file (that's a spec by the customer, so that can't be changed).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by running some script which manipulates the output file generated by the procedure (which produces the result in a single line for a transaction type section group).

try the following:

```
declare @sql varchar(1000)
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "exec dbname.schemaname.procedurename" queryout "filepath" -T -c -r\n -S servername\instanacename'
set @sql = '%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -c "[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(''filepath_which_is_generated_by_procedure'') -replace ''\|([24]\|)'',\"`r`n`$1\"  | Set-Content ''finaloutputfilepath'' 
exec xp_cmdshell @sql
```

I used `PowerShell` to accomplish this.

**Output:**
[image: Output_Sample]

Comment: Yeah - we're coming to that conclusion - use a batch file to modify the data file after it's generated. It's not ideal for our situation, but we're coming to the conclusion that SSRS just can't do what I'm outlining here. Thanks!